# Disable and bypass the angular routing when not in route url

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

How do I disable and bypass the routing of Angular when I have static page or any other page (for example, PHP rendered view), I want to perform a full page reload to the routed link. I am having hybrid PHP and Angularjs app. I want to go to my webserver and not redirected to /someurl by Angular's routing. How do I do this?

Is there any solution other than **target="_self"**, as I've tried using this and it works fine. But it is to messy, each and every time I have to insert it on every hyperlink which I want to bypass.

Comment: Isn't it just a normal `<a href` in Angular?

Comment: yes it is normal <a href

Comment: also, this question is interesting for ajax calls and/or ang2+

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AngularJS and Route Provider, try this to reload the route.

$route.reload()

You can refer the angular official documentations
[angularjs route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

I'm doing hope this help.